# How strong an equivalence does 'ut' imply?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for a nuanced answer here about what kind of connotation 'ut' carries when being used comparatively.

Does 'ut' usually have a broad meaning such as the English word 'like' or is it usually precise such as 'in the same manner'?

Is it possibly even more neutral, functioning like a mere conjunctive?

Here is an example:

> *Est autem hoc sacramentum poenitentiae lapsis post baptismum ad
> salutem necessarium ut nondum regeneratis ipse baptismus.*
>
> English: And this sacrament of Penance is, for those who have fallen
> after baptism, necessary unto salvation; as baptism itself is for
> those who have not as yet been regenerated.

To state the question more precisely, is 'ut', when meaning 'as', more of a conjunctive or comparative?

If comparative, how precise an equivalence does it imply? A loose one or in the exact same manner?

If one wanted to state a stronger equivalence between the comparands what could one use instead? 'Simili modo'?

Comment: Google books is a good source for those questions. Give it a try.